# create infographic in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Please, I need help building an infographic in my Android App. is there any way I can create it. this is an example
[image of infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnaBZ.png)

Comment: Use MPChartLib, Pie graph will help you.

Comment: it is off-topic to ask for a library here

Comment: @Shane will try that now. thanks